# ZFS slow read with 8 drive 4 vdev striped mirror pool

Tags: hard-drive, raid, zfs

I have eight 3TB Western Digital Red SATA drives sdb through sdi that I use in my pool.

My boot and OS drive is a an 850 EVO SSD on sda.

The eight WD drives are on a Supermicro AOC-SAS2LP-MV8 Add-on Card, 8-channel SAS/SATA adapter with 600 Mbyte/s per channel in a PCIE 3.0 x16 running at x8 on a Supermicro ATX DDR4 LGA 1151 C7Z170-OCE-O motherboard.

My server and ZFS setup is as follows:

```
[root@nas ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

[root@nas ~]# uname -a
Linux nas.whittenberg.domain 3.10.0-327.28.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Aug 3 11:11:39 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@nas ~]# cat /var/log/dmesg | grep ZFS
[    0.793572] ZFS: Loaded module v0.6.5.7-1, ZFS pool version 5000, ZFS filesystem version 5
[root@nas ~]# cat /var/log/dmesg | grep SPL
[    0.777144] SPL: Loaded module v0.6.5.7-1

[root@nas ~]# cat /etc/modprobe.d/zfs.conf
# disable prefetch = 1
options zfs zfs_prefetch_disable=0
# set arc max to 48GB. I have 64GB in my server
options zfs zfs_arc_max=51539607552
# set size to 128k same as file system block size
options zfs zfs_vdev_cache_size=1310720
options zfs zfs_vdev_cache_max=1310720
options zfs zfs_read_chunk_size=1310720
options zfs zfs_vdev_cache_bshift=12
options zfs zfs_read_chunk_size=1310720
# Set thes to 10 so we get better IO at cost of banwidth
options zfs zfs_vdev_async_read_max_active=10
options zfs zfs_vdev_async_read_min_active=10
options zfs zfs_vdev_async_write_max_active=10
options zfs zfs_vdev_async_write_min_active=10
options zfs zfs_vdev_sync_read_max_active=10
options zfs zfs_vdev_sync_read_min_active=10
options zfs zfs_vdev_sync_write_max_active=10
options zfs zfs_vdev_sync_write_min_active=10

[root@nas ~]# zpool status
  pool: myraid
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 0h16m with 0 errors on Sun Aug  7 01:40:49 2016
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        myraid      ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdb     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdc     ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-1  ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdd     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sde     ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-2  ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdf     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdg     ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-3  ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdh     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdi     ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

[root@nas ~]# zpool iostat -v
               capacity     operations    bandwidth
pool        alloc   free   read  write   read  write
----------  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----
myraid       382G  10.5T    119     35  14.0M   606K
  mirror    95.5G  2.63T     29      8  3.49M   149K
    sdb         -      -     28      8  3.50M   153K
    sdc         -      -     28      8  3.50M   153K
  mirror    95.5G  2.63T     29      8  3.49M   151K
    sdd         -      -     28      8  3.50M   155K
    sde         -      -     28      8  3.50M   155K
  mirror    95.5G  2.63T     29      8  3.49M   152K
    sdf         -      -     28      8  3.50M   156K
    sdg         -      -     28      8  3.50M   156K
  mirror    95.5G  2.63T     29      9  3.49M   155K
    sdh         -      -     28      9  3.50M   159K
    sdi         -      -     28      9  3.50M   159K
----------  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----

[root@nas ~]# zfs get all
NAME    PROPERTY              VALUE                  SOURCE
myraid  type                  filesystem             -
myraid  creation              Sat Aug  6 21:01 2016  -
myraid  used                  382G                   -
myraid  available             10.2T                  -
myraid  referenced            382G                   -
myraid  compressratio         1.05x                  -
myraid  mounted               yes                    -
myraid  quota                 none                   default
myraid  reservation           none                   default
myraid  recordsize            128K                   local
myraid  mountpoint            /myraid                default
myraid  sharenfs              off                    default
myraid  checksum              fletcher4              local
myraid  compression           lz4                    local
myraid  atime                 off                    local
myraid  devices               on                     default
myraid  exec                  on                     default
myraid  setuid                on                     default
myraid  readonly              off                    default
myraid  zoned                 off                    default
myraid  snapdir               hidden                 default
myraid  aclinherit            restricted             default
myraid  canmount              on                     default
myraid  xattr                 on                     default
myraid  copies                1                      default
myraid  version               5                      -
myraid  utf8only              off                    -
myraid  normalization         none                   -
myraid  casesensitivity       sensitive              -
myraid  vscan                 off                    default
myraid  nbmand                off                    default
myraid  sharesmb              off                    default
myraid  refquota              none                   default
myraid  refreservation        none                   default
myraid  primarycache          all                    local
myraid  secondarycache        all                    default
myraid  usedbysnapshots       0                      -
myraid  usedbydataset         382G                   -
myraid  usedbychildren        1.98M                  -
myraid  usedbyrefreservation  0                      -
myraid  logbias               latency                local
myraid  dedup                 off                    local
myraid  mlslabel              none                   default
myraid  sync                  disabled               local
myraid  refcompressratio      1.05x                  -
myraid  written               382G                   -
myraid  logicalused           403G                   -
myraid  logicalreferenced     403G                   -
myraid  filesystem_limit      none                   default
myraid  snapshot_limit        none                   default
myraid  filesystem_count      none                   default
myraid  snapshot_count        none                   default
myraid  snapdev               hidden                 default
myraid  acltype               off                    default
myraid  context               none                   default
myraid  fscontext             none                   default
myraid  defcontext            none                   default
myraid  rootcontext           none                   default
myraid  relatime              off                    default
myraid  redundant_metadata    all                    default
myraid  overlay               off                    default

[root@nas ~]# zpool get all
NAME    PROPERTY                    VALUE                       SOURCE
myraid  size                        10.9T                       -
myraid  capacity                    3%                          -
myraid  altroot                     -                           default
myraid  health                      ONLINE                      -
myraid  guid                        1068639342092444414         default
myraid  version                     -                           default
myraid  bootfs                      -                           default
myraid  delegation                  on                          default
myraid  autoreplace                 off                         default
myraid  cachefile                   -                           default
myraid  failmode                    wait                        default
myraid  listsnapshots               off                         default
myraid  autoexpand                  off                         default
myraid  dedupditto                  0                           default
myraid  dedupratio                  1.00x                       -
myraid  free                        10.5T                       -
myraid  allocated                   382G                        -
myraid  readonly                    off                         -
myraid  ashift                      0                           default
myraid  comment                     -                           default
myraid  expandsize                  -                           -
myraid  freeing                     0                           default
myraid  fragmentation               1%                          -
myraid  leaked                      0                           default
myraid  feature@async_destroy       enabled                     local
myraid  feature@empty_bpobj         enabled                     local
myraid  feature@lz4_compress        active                      local
myraid  feature@spacemap_histogram  active                      local
myraid  feature@enabled_txg         active                      local
myraid  feature@hole_birth          active                      local
myraid  feature@extensible_dataset  enabled                     local
myraid  feature@embedded_data       active                      local
myraid  feature@bookmarks           enabled                     local
myraid  feature@filesystem_limits   enabled                     local
myraid  feature@large_blocks        enabled                     local

[root@nas ~]# zdb | grep ashift
            ashift: 12
            ashift: 12
            ashift: 12
            ashift: 12

[root@nas ~]# lsblk  -t -e 11,1
NAME                ALIGNMENT MIN-IO OPT-IO PHY-SEC LOG-SEC ROTA SCHED RQ-SIZE  RA WSAME
sda                         0    512      0     512     512    0 cfq       128 128    0B
+-sda1                      0    512      0     512     512    0 cfq       128 128    0B
+-sda2                      0    512      0     512     512    0 cfq       128 128    0B
+-sda3                      0    512      0     512     512    0 cfq       128 128    0B
  +-centos_nas-swap         0    512      0     512     512    0           128 128    0B
  +-centos_nas-root         0    512      0     512     512    0           128 128    0B
  +-centos_nas-home         0    512      0     512     512    0           128 128    0B
sdb                         0   4096      0    4096     512    1 noop      128 128    0B
+-sdb1                      0   4096      0    4096     512    1 noop      128 128    0B
+-sdb9                      0   4096      0    4096     512    1 noop      128 128    0B
sdc                         0   4096      0    4096     512    1 noop      128 128    0B
+-sdc1                      0   4096      0    4096     512    1 noop      128 128    0B
+-sdc9                      0   4096      0    4096     512    1 noop      128 128    0B
sdd                         0   4096      0    4096     512    1 noop      128 128    0B
+-sdd1                      0   4096      0    4096     512    1 noop      128 128    0B
+-sdd9                      0   4096      0    4096     512    1 noop      128 128    0B
sde                         0   4096      0    4096     512    1 noop      128 128    0B
+-sde1                      0   4096      0    4096     512    1 noop      128 128    0B
+-sde9                      0   4096      0    4096     512    1 noop      128 128    0B
sdf                         0   4096      0    4096     512    1 noop      128 128    0B
+-sdf1                      0   4096      0    4096     512    1 noop      128 128    0B
+-sdf9                      0   4096      0    4096     512    1 noop      128 128    0B
sdg                         0   4096      0    4096     512    1 noop      128 128    0B
+-sdg1                      0   4096      0    4096     512    1 noop      128 128    0B
+-sdg9                      0   4096      0    4096     512    1 noop      128 128    0B
sdh                         0   4096      0    4096     512    1 noop      128 128    0B
+-sdh1                      0   4096      0    4096     512    1 noop      128 128    0B
+-sdh9                      0   4096      0    4096     512    1 noop      128 128    0B
sdi                         0   4096      0    4096     512    1 noop      128 128    0B
+-sdi1                      0   4096      0    4096     512    1 noop      128 128    0B
+-sdi9                      0   4096      0    4096     512    1 noop      128 128    0B
```

My problem is that when I read a file for the first time, over my 10 Gbit/s connection (DAC PC to Server), or use `rsync` from pool to the SSD in the server, I get just over 100 Mbyte/s. If I read the same file a second time I get 1.2 Gbyte/s across the 10 Gbit/s DAC connection and 380 Mbyte/s from pool to SSD.

I reboot the server and run a test reading from pool to SSD:

```
[root@nas ~]# rsync -h --progress /myraid/testmovie.avi /home/samba/testmovie.avi
testmovie.avi
       1.08G 100%   79.59MB/s    0:00:12 (xfer#1, to-check=0/1)

sent 1.08G bytes  received 31 bytes  80.21M bytes/sec
total size is 1.08G  speedup is 1.00
```

Then I do the same after it has been read once:

```
[root@nas ~]# rsync -h --progress /myraid/testmovie.avi /home/samba/testmovie.avi
testmovie.avi
       1.08G 100%  394.54MB/s    0:00:02 (xfer#1, to-check=0/1)

sent 1.08G bytes  received 31 bytes  433.13M bytes/sec
total size is 1.08G  speedup is 1.00
```

Any pointers? Should I not get the read speed of four drives on the first read?

Comment: I'm not good at it, but I think you should look into Dtrace to get a definitive answer. Check for "dtrace performance iops", or variations.

Answer (score 2):

## Theoretically speaking

In a *very theoretical world*, from your pool configuration (four vdevs, each a two-disk mirror) you could expect a read bandwidth equivalent of eight times the speed of one disk. That's because:

- In a mirror vdev, [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) is able to read different blocks of data from both disks concurrently
- In a multi-vdev pool, ZFS will automatically stripe your data, so it can - again - read from multiple vdevs concurrently

[Western Digital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Digital) claims that a 3 TB Red drive can read at more than 140 MB/s. That is not going to happen, at least not all the time. So let's assume you can get 100 MB/s from one of those drives. When they are combined in your pool configuration, you could *theoretically* get up to 800 MB/s read bandwidth.

## Welcome to the real world

Now, let me be clear: 800 MB/s, **that is probably not going to  happen!** Not because ZFS lies to you, but because that bandwidth calculation is based on the assumption that hardware is not getting in your way. But it does, so you don't get theoretical speeds under real workload.

Of course, I understand you still expect some reasonable performance improvement by the combination of many disks into one bigger pool.

## What happened then?

Let's take a look at your tests: you get 80 MB/s the first time you copy a big file with [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync), then the second time you do the same thing, you get 400 MB/s. The explanation for the difference is [Adaptive Replacement Cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#ZFS_cache:_ARC_.28L1.29.2C_L2ARC.2C_ZIL) (ARC) and I believe you already know that. I will just say it for the sake of completeness.

ZFS ARC provides a mechanism to store frequently accessed data in RAM.

The first time you read a file from a ZFS dataset, ZFS has to actually read data from disk; in the meantime, it populates its read cache. The second time you read the same file, you get data straight from RAM - and you said you have enough on your system to hold the full 1.08 GB file. This means the speed you see when copying the file again with rsync (400 MB/s) is not related with your physical disks in the ZFS pool. We can think of it as the write speed of your [SSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive) `sda` drive. To be precise, not the *raw* write speed of your SSD: it's the speed you get when using rsync to read data from a very low latency and high bandwidth media (RAM memory) and write to your SSD drive (which also has very low latency). Plus, I believe we should consider that Linux is probably using all that available RAM memory to cache the async writes (making assumptions here!) to the SSD drive partition.

So, at this point, **a question arises**: if your RAM-to-SSD write speed seems to be 400 MB/s, why do you only get 80 MB/s when ZFS is actually reading from disk? That’s less than a single disk speed! Clearly, the SSD itself can't be blamed, and we were expecting a lot more from all those drives in the ZFS pool!

So, to be completely honest: I don't have a full answer. After considering everything I said so far, my **partial answer to your question** is:

- To me it looks like the bandwidth is low because of high I/O activity, meaning that rsync is not actually allowing for a straight sequential read of the big file, instead is generating a lot of I/O, which can severely impact streaming performance if the drive has some latency involved with lots of I/O. Let’s remember that Western Digital Red disks are for [NAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage) applications, which means they are intended for decent bandwidth and good $/GB ratio, not for high IOPS. When you did the same exact thing from RAM (low latency media), the overall streaming performance was OK.
- rsync is NOT a good way of *benchmarking* your ZFS pool - or anything else. If you google for *rsync performance* you see evidence of it being slower than a normal file copy - for good reasons, I think: speed is not what you use rsync for. I would look for some other way of benchmarking. Even just [`dd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29) or `cp` could be better choices for sequential read/write test. You can look at [this article](https://lwn.net/Articles/400489/) for some inspiration.
- Also, I would try to figure out the *real* single disk read performance, running tests before the disks are even added to a ZFS pool. Destroy the pool (you will lose data: first make a backup if necessary!), run tests on every single disk, then define the pool again and do some more testing. Then, you can apply the math based on the real speed you observed and make assumptions - again - about the *theoretical* read bandwidth, based on your ZFS pool configuration (4 vdevs * 2 disks mirror = single disk bandwidth * 8).
- If you run tests on every single disk - before you use them in a pool - you might find out one or more disks are not in good shape. If you just bought the disks, return the bad ones and ask for replacements.
- If you run tests on every single disk and find out they all perform consistently slow, you could be facing a hardware related problem - either configuration, driver support or other similar issues.
- I would try different hardware configurations (if possible) and run tests against each. Run the tests using a single mirror vdev pool, than try combining more vdevs into the mix. See if that gives you the expected results.

**To wrap up**: you need to methodically find out where your bottleneck is. Don’t assume it is ZFS itself; it’s probably not. Try different configurations, and run tests using appropriate tools for the job.

I’m not a benchmark or testing expert, so I’m not going to give you advice on that regard. The Internet is full of wonderful material about the topic. I just wanted to touch on some aspects that are specific to ZFS and hopefully give you a direction to look at.

Comment: BTW, I got the *internal transfer speed* of 3TB WD Red drives from their [specs sheet](http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/SpecSheet/ENG/2879-800002.pdf)

Comment: I did extended disk using the WD Life guard util on my windows 10 PC before installing then into my nas. I also turned off head parking using idle3-tools-0.9.1.tgz after they were in the NAS and available to the OS. All the disk checked out fine. I also have supermicro sas/sata controller that advertises 600MB throughput in a 8x PCIe slot, which i have. My testing has been rsync, dd, cp, and smb across my 10Gb network (using intel dual CNA cards with SFP+ DAC from macine to machine). I get about 112MB using dd, cp, and smb. Oh ya, i have 950 pro m.2 SSD in my PC for the smb test.

Comment: That m.2 SSD benches at over 2,500 read and over 1,500 write (yikes!). Using the same hardware and operating systems, just changing to btrfs, i am getting the 500MB read and writes on non cached files. I appreciate your input and support, but with the success so far with btrfs I am going to try that for a bit. I just upgraded my kernel and btrfs-progs to 4.7 so i have latest btrfs now. System is very stable.

Comment: I use it for vm guest storage across a 10Gb link via NFS to my ESXi server, smb share for windows so i can backup my PC's, and I have Plexmedia server on it so i can stream content both on the LAN and remotely. So far so good :) Thanks!

Comment: And i have 64GB DDR4 RAM in it with a i5-6600k. So plenty of juice for the NAS.

Comment: Tanks to @Peter and the other editors for taking the time to improve the answer.